# Encoding issue when using taglib to read mp3 file metadata with c#

Tags: c#, taglib

I'm using C# to read information from mp3 file metadata. This information in arabic .. when I open this mp3 file by windows media player or any other media player I can read the information very clearly but when I try to read this information by [taglib](http://taglib.github.com/) some files appears right and some other files appears in stranger format it is not arabic and not english.

Answer (score 0):

this is most likely because the encoding stated in the ID3 tag is not the actual encoding used to write the tags, taglib will read the data in the id3 tag using the encoding specified in the tag frame. The end result is you will get a different string because a wrong encoding is used.